# Given a plane equation (ax+by+cz=d), how does one find a point on the plane (x0, y0,z0)?

Tags: plane-geometry

Given a plane equation in the form ax+by+cz=d, how can one find the point (x0, y0, z0)?

I already know what the a,b,c,d coeffiecients are. I am not referring to the x,y,z intercepts

ie. d=-ax0-by0-cz0 See the example here on wolfram

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Plane.html

Comment: Read further in that Wolfram article. It tells you how to find the perpendicular distance from the origin to the plane given the equation, so the nearest point on the plane to the origin is… ?

Comment: thank you for the reply. is this correct  x0=(a*d)/(a^2+b^2+c^2)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's such thing as "The point" on a plane. There are many points and not a special one. However, you can preset 2 of the 3 coords of a particular point on the plane, and find the other one by substituting in the equation.

---

Any further explanation needs more detailing about what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply replace $(x,y)\,$ by $\,(x_0,y_0),\,$ i.e $\;ax_0 + by_0 + cz + d = 0,\;$ and solve the equation for $z_0.$